# Sails Datastore Adapter

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I just created a custom service in sails js and trying to access the database adapter (sails.config.datastores) inside that service, but i'm not able to do that. I tried to use the sails.getDatastore() method and getting sails not defined error.
Here is my adapter connection.

```
url: 'mysql://root:@localhost:3306/users',
```

and my custom service code is

```
var options_default = {
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'root',
password : '',
database : 'users',
table    : 'userInfo',
};
```

How can i access my database adapter in custom service